# How can I refactor this C++ to remove the labels/gotos? 

Tags: c++, c, label, goto

My problem is not really a problem, but I want to make this code look a bit more elegant than it currently is. It has spaghetti code.

Here is a little example of what I got.

```
 int func(...) {
  if ( ... )
  {
    v6 = ESI_1C;
    EBP = 1;
    v5 = 0;
    v21 = 0;
    v19 = 0;
    v25 = ESI_1C;
    if ( packetSize > 1 )
    {
      v26 = (unsigned __int8)initialCryptAnswer;
      v10 = v8 - v6;
      v11 = v6 + 4;
      for ( i = v8 - v6; ; v10 = i )
      {
        v12 = *(DWORD *)(v10 + v11);
        v21 += v12;
        cryptAnswer = (unsigned __int8)cryptTable[(2 * (unsigned __int8)v26)+1];
        v13 = EBP & 3;
        if ( !(EBP & 3) )
          break;
        if ( v13 == 1 ) {
          v16 = cryptAnswer >> 1;
          *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 - v16;
        } else if ( v13 == 2 ) {
          *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 + 2 * cryptAnswer;
        } else if ( v13 == 3 ) {
          v16 = cryptAnswer >> 2;
          *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 - v16;
        }
LABEL_19:
        v17 = *(DWORD *)v11 + v19;
        ++EBP;
        v11 += 4;
        v19 = v17;
        ++v26;
        if ( EBP >= packetSize )
        {
          ESI = v24;
          v5 = v17;
          v6 = v25;
          goto LABEL_22; //kinda like break it's much more because it's instead of a for loop too.
        }
      }
      *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 + 4 * cryptAnswer;
      goto LABEL_19; //this is a looper
    }
LABEL_22:
    result = 1;
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

What can I do to get rid of the labels without messing up the code flow as it's very important part of an encryption function?

Comment: whats CR.SE? sorry I don't know

Comment: `//this goes back into for loop.` ... What?

Comment: it means.. that label goes into the for() loop.. which is why I want to make this more elegant it's really a mind twister right now, but it works perfectly. Label_1 call is outside the for() loop yet it goes back inside it!

Comment: I know what it means. I'm questioning its sanity, not its significance.

Comment: haha believe it or not.. that code above is optimized for speed. But I just want to make it look pretty to the eyes.

Comment: LOL @ Optimized for speed! Have you profiled before started "optimizing" with gotos?

Comment: I think you've left out a little too much of the logic for anybody to really help much -- for example, it's not clear whether `i` changes inside the loop or not. Despite the label/goto, the `goto LABEL_2` is only inside one thing C recognizes as a loop, so it could be replaced with a `break`.

Comment: @SSpoke: Oh sorry it stands for [CodeReview.StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second answer, as the question changed a lot.

The original code looks like, after removing all redundant stuff:

```
for (... ; ; ...)
{
  ...
  if (...)
  {
    break;
  }
  ABC
LABEL_19:
  DEF
}
XYZ;
goto LABEL_19;
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
for (... ; ; ...)
{
  ...
  if (...)
  {
    XYZ;
  }
  else
  {
    ABC
  }

  DEF
}
```

Once you have done this rewrite, you could replace the `goto LABEL_22` with a simple `break`.

**EDIT:** Or more explicitly:

```
for (... ; ; ...)
{
  ...
  if (! (ESP & 3) )
  {
    // This line used to be located after the loop.
    *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 + 4*cryptAnswer;  // 111
  }
  else
  {
    if (v13 == 1)
    {
      ...
    }
    else if (v13 == 2)
    {
      ...
    }
    else if (v13 == 3)
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  // This is where LABEL_19 used to be.

  v17 = ...      // 222
}
```

The rule of thumb when you rewrite code like this is that the code should perform the same actions in the same order as before. You simply can't move code around blindly, and to do this you must understand the flow of the code. In this case, when the first `if` is taken, the line I've marked with `// 111` is first executed, then the line `// 222`, nothing else.

Comment: You FIRST have to fix the `LABEL_19` calamity first. In the code you link to, you still have `if (! (ESP & 3) ) break;`. In my code above, `ABC` refers to the 9-line `if ... else if ... ` section. Start with this rewrite and make sure that it works before starting to make the other.

Comment: Sorry i'm having a brain freezes, you want me to alter the if(!(ESP&3)) instead of breaking to do XYZ? I'm so confused because I know the code on the bottom has to be executed last.. why move it above the 9-line if's it will mess things up. I cannot add a else to that ifelse block because the block after the 9 liner has to be called regardless.

Comment: Your code does a `break;`, runs one line after the `for` loop, then jumps back into the loop. (This is the only time this one line is executed.) It would be better to simply place that line inside the for loop, and place the code that is skipped by this in a new `else` clause.

Comment: @Lindydancer Sorry i'm so slow but i simply cannot understand this. You want me to move `*(DWORD *)v11 = v12 + 4 * cryptAnswer;` on top of `LABEL_19:` which would be where it has to be ran the 2nd time around but not the first time around.. it's not ran only the 2nd time it re-enters the loop and non-stop from there on. Can you please just show me modified code I know you guys hate spoon feeding people but I think I won't figure this out.

Comment: I've updated my answer to more explicitly show what I described. Good luck with the rest of your rewrite.

Comment: that did it I didn't even have to use a else for if/ifelse-block

Comment: @SSpoke: Good for you! However, if you don't include the `else` to skip the other `if`:s, don't come back and say the rewrite didn't work when your input would make both the `if ( !(ESP & 3) )` and one of the `if (v13 == ...)` match ;)

Comment: Thanks Lindy your a hero. I thought about what you said and decided a even better solution. As `if ( !(ESP & 3) )` is the same as `v13` aka `v13 = EBP & 3;` and just added `if(!v13) *(DWORD *)v11 = v12 + 4*cryptAnswer; else if(v13 == 1) {...} else if(v13 == 2) {...}` and so on. From what I gather now before I decompiled this snippet `if ( !(ESP & 3) )` was actually `v13 == 0`, right? so much artificial intelligence rules of for loops would required to figure that one out to improve the decompilers!

Answer (score 1):

The `goto LABEL_1` is never executed, as there is no way out of the `for` loop.

Once this has been removed, you can replace `goto LABEL_2` with a `break`, or even better simply `return 1;` (or `result = 1; return 1;` if `return` is not a local variable.)

Comment: At least as I read it, LABEL_1 is inside the for loop, so lack of exit from the for loop doesn't stop it from being executed.

Comment: LindyDancer's point is that the goto label1 is never executed

Comment: the label1 actually is used, concluded from debugging, as a loop of it's own, which breaks when some variables for the conditional add up and the next label2 call is called.. which is the exit

Comment: `LABEL_1` is inside the loop. However, `goto LABEL_1` is after the loop, and the loop has no termination condition so it will loop forever. This mean that there is no way you can reach `goto LABEL_1`. So it can safely be removed. As no one else if referring to `LABEL_1`, it can be removed. (Of course, this assumes that there are no `break` statements in the left-out bodies of the `if`:s.)

Comment: Lindydancer can you look at screenshot I edited the question.. it's more accurate

Comment: @SSpoke: I've added another answer, the rewrite should be straight-forward even though the code you originally posted differs quite a bit from the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you cut and pasted the code so we can cut and paste it into an editor but basically the line before goto Label_19 needs to go where the break line is. The if statement following the break needs to become an else if and the goto label 22 can become a break (or move the conditional that leads to goto label 22 into the for loop as in my previous answer) into the for loop.

PS: your secret isn't a secret to anyone who has the executable

Comment: ah you are clever! thats where it messed up. the forr loop

Comment: @SSpoke: my previous answer related to your first code sample and doesn't do the same as your screen shot.

Comment: I might as well, it may help people out in the future.

Comment: Haha btw PS. your secret isn't a secret to anyone who has the executable, the code snippet above is to test out a C++ decompiler which is still under development.

Comment: So not only have you "optimized for speed" without profiling, you've got under development something which is literally impossible.  Am I reading this right?

Comment: No it's possible :) the snippet above was created by it, it generates static arrays and dynamic pointers, and attempts to make code as beautifully as it can but sometimes it cannot find the solution and does these LABAL's.. of course all variable names are lost.. but who cares.. if you want to steal a function of code that does something like hashing or something similar like checksums it does the job as easily as copy/paste. It does fail on some _asm{} inlines and it doesn't support c++ classes just yet.